# Can I Commission Something?

Tags: discussion

Is this a good place to commission an art project? Like a car drawing (which is what I'm actually looking for)?
if so, I will add details as to what I need. Otherwise, please point me to another place that would work for that purpose.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not the correct venue to seek workers. There are a ton of web sites dedicated to connecting freelance workers with clients. A Google search would quickly point those sites out.

Answer (score 2):

This site is more dedicated to co-support for designers working on projects like yours.  Several of the people who use this support network for their daily jobs work for sites that do exactly what you are after.

Try Fiverr.com.  I think that will work well for you.

Cheers,

Comment: I didn't realize there was a meta for graphic design, this probably is a better place; and thanks for the suggestion, it could be useful.